# Redirecting to another page after a button is clicked Although there is no navigation code written in click event listener

Tags: angular, angularjs-forms

This is my edit form html template

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <form [formGroup]="recipeForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" [disabled]="!recipeForm.valid">Save</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" formControlName="recipename">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="imageurl">Image URL</label>
            <input type="text" id="imageurl" class="form-control" formControlName="imageurl" #imagePath>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <img [src]="imagePath.value" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="desc">Description</label>
            <textarea  id="desc" cols="20" rows="8" class="form-control" formControlName="desc"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" formArrayName="ingredients">
      <div class="row" *ngFor="let ingredient of recipeForm.get('ingredients').controls;let i=index"[formGroupName]="i" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
        <div class="col-xs-8" >
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <input type="number"  class="form-control" formControlName="amount">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="btn btn-danger form-control" (click)="onDeleteIngredient(i)">X</button>
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onAddIngredient()">Add Ingredient</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>

</div>

</div>
```

This is my edit component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Params, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {RecipeService} from "../recipes.service";
import {FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray,Validators} from  '@angular/forms';
import {Recipe} from "../recipe.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipes-edit',
  templateUrl: './recipes-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipes-edit.component.css'],

})
export class RecipesEditComponent implements OnInit {
id:number;
editMode:boolean=false;
recipeForm:FormGroup;
  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,private recipeService:RecipeService,private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params:Params)=>{
      this.id=+params['id'];
      this.editMode=params['id']!=null;
      this.initForm();

    })
  }
  private initForm(){
    let recipeName='';
    let imageurl='';
    let description='';
    let ingredients=new FormArray([]);
    if(this.editMode) {
      const recipe = this.recipeService.getSingleRecipe(this.id);
      recipeName=recipe.name;
      imageurl=recipe.imagePath;
      description=recipe.description;
      if(recipe['ingredients']){
        for(let ingredient of recipe.ingredients){
          ingredients.push( new FormGroup({
           'name':new FormControl(ingredient.name,Validators.required),
            'amount':new FormControl(ingredient.amount,[Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/^[1-9]+[0-9]*$/)])
          }))
        }
      }

    }
    this.recipeForm=new FormGroup({
      'recipename':new FormControl(recipeName,Validators.required),
      'imageurl':new FormControl(imageurl,Validators.required),
      'desc':new FormControl(description,Validators.required),
      'ingredients': ingredients
    })
  }
  onAddIngredient(){
    (<FormArray>this.recipeForm.get('ingredients')).push(
      new FormGroup({
        'name':new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
        'amount':new FormControl(null,[Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/^[1-9]+[0-9]*$/)])
      })
    )
}
onSubmit(){
    const newRecipe=new Recipe(
      this.recipeForm.value['recipename'],
      this.recipeForm.value['desc'],
      this.recipeForm.value['imageurl'],

      this.recipeForm.value['ingredients']
    );
  if(this.editMode) {
    this.recipeService.updateRecipe(this.id, newRecipe)


  }else{
    this.recipeService.addRecipe(newRecipe);

  }
  this.onCancel();


  }
  onCancel(){
  this.router.navigate(['../'],{relativeTo:this.route})

  }
  onDeleteIngredient(){

  }

}
```

The problem i am facing is when i click the Add Ingredient button it is redirecting back to another path instead of adding an ingredient field. But i have never written a code that cause redirection in onAddIngredient() method.

I have written the navigation code  only for  cancel and  save button. I am not able to figure out what actually the reason that causes this redirection. Can somebody help me out from this. I wanted redirection to be happened whenever save or cancel button is clicked.

Comment: Add `type="button"` to the add ingredient button. Without specifying type it defaults to submit.

Comment: Eventhough i change the type to button,it's not working

Comment: add `(click)="onAddIngredient(); $event.preventDefault()"`

Comment: you should not listen to the click event here, you already listen to the submit event, you just need to set the button type to submit, type='submit'